# How to search a value with LIKE %% inside a SQL Array Type filed

Tags: sql, arrays, select, sql-like

I was wondering how can I search inside a SQL Array type field with the LIKE operator. I would like to have something like that :

User has some roles and roles is an array SQL type:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.roles LIKE '%Role1%' OR user.roles LIKE '%Role2%'
```

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using? What do you mean by *"SQL Array type"*?

Comment: which DB ?? post some sample data for appropriate answer .

Comment: I'm guessing you have a user table with a roles column containing a list of roles possibly delimited by commas, or in an xml structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #roles ([role] VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #roles
        ( role )
VALUES  ( 'W' ),
        ( 'X' ),
        ( 'Y' ),
        ( 'Z' ),
        ( 'A' ) 

SELECT distinct u.* 
FROM user u 
JOIN #roles r ON u.roles LIKE '%'+ r.[role] +'%'
```

You will possibly get more then one of the same user so `distinct` is used.